# Primefaces - Csv into datatable

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

Well, I have a String that is like a csv file and I need to show this using primefaces datatable or something like that. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the PrimeFaces showcase, it can work with an arrayList. So all you need is a csv to ArrayList converter. That is plain java and lots and lots of examples about that can be found on the internet.